# How to generate pb2 and ob2_grpc files in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, protocol-buffers

So I'm trying to use the protobuff on pycharm but I need to generate those two files mentioned, I've created a .proto type file, I have all the pip packages installed and everything but none of the commands I find online seem to work properly. Any help in regards to what command needs to be issued here would be appreciated.

Comment: `protoc` is normally used to turn proto files into pb.cc/h files (or other extensions depending on your target language). That may be different for GRPC since that adds service definitions into the mix. But regardless, you should be stating what you *have* tried so far, rather than just using the unhelpful "nothing I tried has worked".

Comment: See the [Python Quickstart for gRPC](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/)